# WebI report issue with Windows Boxi 4.1 when report is accessed in a web app hosted in Weblogic 10.3.6 in Redhat Linux

Tags: redhat, weblogic-10.x, business-objects

From our web application, we are accessing a WebI report.

The web application is in Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga). We are using WebLogic Server Version: 10.3.6.0. The java used is
 "1.7.0_72", Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14),
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)

The BO server is SAP BusinessObjects BI Platform 4.1 Support Pack 5
Version: 14.1.5.1501. It is hosted in Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, Service pack 1, 64 bit

We have a report in our web application that uses WebI report. For this, I have set PRE_CLASSPATH in setDomain.sh as follows.

```
PRE_CLASSPATH=cryptojFIPS.jar:dsl_engine.jar:sdk.core.jar:TraceLog.jar:sdk.core.server.corba.jar:sdk.core.session.jar:sdk.core.server.common.jar:sdk.core.session.cms.jar:sdk.core.server.jar:cecore.jar:celib.jar:logging.jar:aspectjrt.jar:corbaidl.jar:ebus405.jar:ceaspect.jar:bcm.jar:inproc_container.jar:CTPlugin_idl.jar:cdz_cluster_mgmt_types_idl.jar:GenericContainer_proxy.jar:IEPlugin_idl.jar:GenericContainer_idl.jar:org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.4.2.v200902171115.jar:org.eclipse.emf.common_2.4.0.v200902171115.jar:aspectjtools.jar:ceplugins_core.jar:cesession.jar:cvom.jar:dsl_sdk_services.jar:cdzidl.jar:ie_proxies.jar:commons-codec-1.3.jar:rebean.common.jar:rebean.wi.adapter.jar:rebean.wi.jar:rebean.wi.model.jar:rom.jar:rebean.wi.server.requests.jar:protobuf.jar:rebean.wi.server.commands.jar:rebean.wi.server.jar:webi_proxies.jar:xpp3-1.1.3_8.jar
```

All Jars are taken from Boxi 4.1 distribution. 
I have resolved multiple class not found, FIPS compliance issues and resolved all of them to reach this stage. It has literally been a dogged fight.

Now the error that I get is as below and I have not able to get past this.

> Blockquote

(Note: It works cleanly if I use windows weblogic for our application server)

> Blockquote

Now the error

```
Unable to instantiate ReportEngine.
    at com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.ReportEngines.createReportEngine(ReportEngines.java:290)
    at com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.ReportEngines.getService(ReportEngines.java:249)
    at OurPackage.OurClass.OurMethod
    at OurPackage.OurClass.OurMethod
    at OurPackage.OurClass.OurMethod
    at OurPackage.OurClass.OurMethod
    at OurPackage.OurClass.OurMethod
    at OurPackage.OurClass.OurMethod
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:63)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at OurPackage.OurClass.OurMethod.util.CrossSiteScriptingFilter.doFilter(CrossSiteScriptingFilter.java:132)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at OurPackage.OurClass.OurMethod.util.SeperatorFilter.doFilter(SeperatorFilter.java:41)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
    Caused by: com.businessobjects.sdk.core.CoreException: com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice configuration errors:

    1) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.config.AbstractConfigurator$1.configure(AbstractConfigurator.java:90):
    A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.common.storage.IStorageManagerService was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.config.AbstractConfigurator$1.configure(AbstractConfigurator.java:90).

   2) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:132):
   A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerCommand annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.blob.BlobRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:132).

   3) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:132):
   A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerCommand annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.blob.BlobChunkRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:132).

    4) Error at    com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:132):
     A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerCommand annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.blob.BlobInfoRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:132).

    5) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:132):
    A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerCommand annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.blob.CloseBlobRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:132).

    6) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:132):
     A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerCommand annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.blob.UploadBlobRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:132).

    7) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:132):
    A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerCommand annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.blob.UploadBlobChunkRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:132).

    8) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:132):
    A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerCommand annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.resource.AddResourceRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:132).

    9) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:132):
    A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerCommand annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.resource.GetResourceListRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:132).

    10) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:132):
    A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerCommand annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.resource.UpdateResourceRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:132).

    11) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.configure(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:112):
     A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.marshalling.IDataMarshaler annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.corba.generic.container.CTPlugin.TokenMode) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.BlobModule.configure(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:112).

    12) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CMSModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:82):
     A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerCommand annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.requests.SelectDataFromCMSRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CMSModule.bindCommand(CorbaServerConfigurator.java:82).

    13) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindCommand(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:109):
    A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerCommand annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.requests.InitInstanceRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindCommand(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:109).

    14) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindCommand(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:109):
     A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerCommand annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.requests.CloseInstanceRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindCommand(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:109).

    15) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121):
     A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerRequestHandler annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.requests.InitInstanceRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121).

16) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerRequestHandler annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.requests.CloseInstanceRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121).

17) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerRequestHandler annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.blob.BlobRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121).

18) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerRequestHandler annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.blob.BlobChunkRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121).

19) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerRequestHandler annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.blob.BlobInfoRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121).

20) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerRequestHandler annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.blob.CloseBlobRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121).

21) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerRequestHandler annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.blob.UploadBlobRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121).

22) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerRequestHandler annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.blob.UploadBlobChunkRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121).

23) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerRequestHandler annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.resource.AddResourceRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121).

24) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerRequestHandler annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.resource.UpdateResourceRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsModule.bindHandler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:121).

25) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerMessage annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=core.BlobInfoRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181).

26) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerMessage annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=core.CloseBlobRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181).

27) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerMessage annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=core.BlobRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181).

28) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerMessage annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=core.BlobChunkRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181).

29) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerMessage annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=core.BlobResponse) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181).

30) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerMessage annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=core.MapServerResponse) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181).

31) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerMessage annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=core.CloneSessionRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181).

32) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerMessage annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=core.CloseSessionRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181).

33) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerMessage annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=core.ConnectSessionRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181).

34) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerMessage annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=core.CreateSessionRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181).

35) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerMessage annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=core.UploadBlobRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181).

36) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerMessage annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=core.UploadBlobChunkRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181).

37) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerMessage annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=core.AddResourceRequest) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181).

38) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerMessage annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=core.AddResourceResponse) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181).

39) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.IServerMessage annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=core.UploadBlobServerResponse) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.CommonCommandsXMLMarshalerModule.bindXMLMarshaler(CommonCommandsConfigurator.java:181).

........ and so on ............

90) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.ServerXMLMarshalerModule.configure(ServerConfigurator.java:98):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.marshalling.IDataMarshaler annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.ITechnicalResponse) was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.server.internal.config.ServerXMLMarshalerModule.configure(ServerConfigurator.java:98).

91) Error at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.session.internal.SessionModule.configure(SessionConfigurator.java:37):
 A binding to com.businessobjects.sdk.core.internal.service.ISharedDataHandler was already configured at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.session.internal.SessionModule.configure(SessionConfigurator.java:37).

91 error[s]
    at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.internal.guice.GenericFactory.<init>(GenericFactory.java:43)
    at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.internal.CoreImpl.setEnvironment(CoreImpl.java:90)
    at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.Core.init(Core.java:139)
    at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.Core.checkInit(Core.java:157)
    at com.businessobjects.sdk.core.Core.create(Core.java:456)
    at com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.internal.ReportEngineFactory.makeOCCA(ReportEngineFactory.java:76)
    at com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.ReportEngines.createReportEngine(ReportEngines.java:281)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice configuration errors:
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to do ?Are you using jsp pages and using the old rebean api ?

Comment: We are using Rebean API

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because the classpath of your application makes reference several time to the same jars. You should ensure that each BOE jar is imported only once.

In my opinion, you should use our RESTful SDK which will avoid you all these classpath issues since no specific jar are required to use it.
You will find all necessary information on the RESTful API here: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-43224